# I am a little confused on how to get my skybox to match my camera view

Tags: c++, graphics

31. Move the skybox to be at the same position as the camera.  Don’t forget to use Push/Pop matrix commands.  You should now see sand blocking your view of everything else.
    •   You can determine the position of the camera by looking at the first three numbers following gluLookAt. So, if you see gluLookAt(2.0, 1.0, 4.0, …) then the camera is located at (2, 1, 4) in X/Y/Z space.

I dont think it is supposed to be a glscaled because it doesnt look right when i compile it.  I am not too sure what I am supposed to use instead though.

```
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(2.0, 3.0, 4.0,  // (x, y, z) camera eye position
          0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  // (x, y, z) camera look at position
          0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // (x, y, z) camera up direction

// camera is now set up - any drawing before here will display incorrectly


glPushMatrix();

glScaled(2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
skybox.draw();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: You're right, using `glScaled` will just [resize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)) the geometry of your skybox. That function doesn't [change the position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)) of the skybox at all.

Comment: Thanks Romen, I got it to work!!!